# Long Press Gesture called multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, long-press, swift4.1, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am getting an issue with UILongPressGestureRecognizer, I have used this code:-

```
func addLongPressGesture(){
        let lngPr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress(gesture:)))
        lngPr.delaysTouchesEnded = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(lngPr)
    }
    @objc func handleLongPress(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer){
       
        if selectedIndexPath != nil && delegate != nil{
            self.delegate?.delegateLongPressed(atIndexPath: selectedIndexPath!)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hey you need to check the state of UILongPressGesture to reform your functions 
Try this :-

```
func addLongPressGesture(){
        let lngPr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress(gesture:)))
        lngPr.delaysTouchesEnded = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(lngPr)
    }
    @objc func handleLongPress(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer){
        if gesture.state == .ended{
        if selectedIndexPath != nil && delegate != nil{
            self.delegate?.delegateLongPressed(atIndexPath: selectedIndexPath!)
        }
        }
    }
```